# Result set based off quantity of subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries that I am trying to combine; basically the first query finds out how many items of specific product has been dispatched

```
SELECT 
    T0.SOPOrderReturnLineID,
    T1.Quantity AS 'QtyDespatched',
    T0.LineQuantity As 'OrderQty',
    T1.SopLinkId AS 'DespatchSopLinkId',
    T1.ItemCode 
FROM
    SOPOrderReturnLine AS T0
LEFT JOIN 
    DespatchedItems AS T1 ON T0.SOPOrderReturnLineID = T1.SopLinkId
WHERE
    T1.SopLinkId IS NOT NULL AND
    T1.ItemCode = 'GSNOBAS60GW'
GROUP BY 
    T1.SopLinkId, T0.SOPOrderReturnLineID, 
    T1.Quantity, T0.LineQuantity, T1.ItemCode
```

Here is a sample result set of the both queries

[image: ql]

This second query finds out how many of that item has been made in total by summing the quantities I don't want the items appearing in the above result set until the `OrderQty` match the 3 that has been made so far how is this done ?.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, T1.Quantity))
FROM 
    SOPOrderReturnLine AS T0
LEFT JOIN 
    DespatchedItems AS T1 ON T0.SOPOrderReturnLineID = T1.SopLinkId
WHERE
    T1.SopLinkId IS NOT NULL AND
    T1.ItemCode = 'GSNOBAS60GW'
```

Comment: I do not understand the exact problem yet. I think you should elaborate further what you have now, why is it bad and what would you like to have instead.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question because I'm getting the wrong message between `T1.Quantity` and `T0.LineQuantity`. You bring up your second query suming up the `T1.Quantity`, but your question is about `T0.LineQuantity`.

Comment: Images of code and data is pretty useless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: In your first query, the use of T1 in the where clause turns your outer join into an inner join. In addition, use of group by without an aggregate is logically the same as "distinct". Both are often signs of a logically flawed query. And this may be part of your problem - your 2nd query will accurately (ignoring the convert to int) sum all selected rows, not just the distinct ones.

Comment: @SeanLange both code has been included above and yes I will restate the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is just a typical aggregate query. Something like this. Notice I changed your aliases to something relevant to the table. Generic aliases are really challenging to work with. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

```
SELECT 
    ORL.SOPOrderReturnLineID,
    SUM(DI.Quantity) AS 'QtyDespatched',
    ORL.LineQuantity As 'OrderQty',
    DI.SopLinkId AS 'DespatchSopLinkId',
    DI.ItemCode 
FROM
    SOPOrderReturnLine AS ORL
LEFT JOIN 
    Fuel_DespatchedItems AS DI ON ORL.SOPOrderReturnLineID = DI.SopLinkId
WHERE
    DI.SopLinkId IS NOT NULL AND
    DI.ItemCode = 'GSNOBAS60GW'
GROUP BY 
    DI.SopLinkId
    , ORL.SOPOrderReturnLineID
    , ORL.LineQuantity
    , DI.ItemCode
```

If you want to filter aggregate you use the [HAVING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.

Just add the HAVING after the group by.

```
SELECT 
    ORL.SOPOrderReturnLineID,
    SUM(DI.Quantity) AS 'QtyDespatched',
    ORL.LineQuantity As 'OrderQty',
    DI.SopLinkId AS 'DespatchSopLinkId',
    DI.ItemCode 
FROM
    SOPOrderReturnLine AS ORL
LEFT JOIN 
    Fuel_DespatchedItems AS DI ON ORL.SOPOrderReturnLineID = DI.SopLinkId
WHERE
    DI.SopLinkId IS NOT NULL AND
    DI.ItemCode = 'GSNOBAS60GW'
GROUP BY 
    DI.SopLinkId
    , ORL.SOPOrderReturnLineID
    , ORL.LineQuantity
    , DI.ItemCode
HAVING SUM(DI.Quantity) < ORL.LineQuantity
```

Comment: 100% what i need however how would i do a comparison for when the qtry despatched is less than the order qty i only want the data to be returned

Comment: When you want to filter aggregates you use having. So in this case something like HAVING SUM(DI.Quantity) < ORL.LineQuantity

Comment: Can you demostrate eidting answer thank u mate for being one good one helping a fellow coder.